# Understanding Apache Order and Allow in <Directory> directive

Tags: apache-2.2

I have tried reading the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) although to be honest I am still finding it hard to understand and get my head around what the Order/Allow actually does and what should be the default settings for web server.

I have the following default config, where I have turned off .htaccess and symbolic links.

Although I am not really sure what the `Order Allow,Deny` and `Allow from all` actually does? Should I change this to Allow from 127.0.0.1?

```
<Directory />
Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Additionally do I need the below `<Files>` or is there a better way of writing this for apache?

```
<Directory /var/www/example/subdomains/dev/public/webapp>
    RewriteEngine Off

    <Files *>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|swf|ps|flv)$">
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Order Allow,Deny` means that the `Allow` rules are processed before the `Deny` rules. If client doesn't match the `Allow` rules or it does match the `Deny` rule, it will be denied access.

So,

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

means that any client can access to your web server.

> I want to turn off .htaccess and symbolic links.

You already did that with `AllowOverride None` and `Options -FollowSymLinks`

```
<Directory /var/www/example/subdomains/dev/public/webapp>
    RewriteEngine Off

    <Files *>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|swf|ps|flv)$">
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

This config did the following:

- disable rewriting engine
- client will be denied access to the all files in `webapp` folder
  except for images, js, swf, ...

Pay attention to:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

it tells Apache to deny any access.

Comment: Thanks quanta, it is now a lot clearer. Although what are the rules you speak about for the allow/deny?

Comment: I mean `Deny from <address>` and `Allow from <hostname>` are rules.